# (NestJs) Migration name argument to cli command

Tags: node.js, migration, nestjs, command-line-interface

I have a problem with giving an argument to command in console when I run the command for migrations.

This is my "typeorm" command.

```
    "typeorm": "node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js",
```

This is "migration:generate"

```
    "migration:generate": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:generate -d src/database/type-orm-config-migrations.ts ./src/database/migrations/$npm_config_name",
```

I need to send the name of migration which I want to create into cli instead of $npm_config_name.

I tried to run

- "npm run migration:generate --name" ;
- "npm run migration:generate -name" ;
- "npm run migration:generate name" ;

Nothing works.

Comment: which version of typeorm are you using? btw this is just typeorm stuff.

Comment: I use 0.3.11 version of typeorm

Comment: same here, did you manage to pass name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You Can Follow This Github Link:** https://github.com/MIShuvro/dream-tour

```
npm run migration:generate --name=changes_entity
```

Comment: This link is unavailable, but this command works, thank you

Comment: Ohh sorry, this is my private repo, sad.